# textarea вставляет перевод строки

Tags: javascript, html

Есть textarea в которую я через `$("#text").val(res);` записываю текст. Проблема в том, что текст начинает записываться со второй строки, будто вначале стоит `<br>`. В чем может быть проблема?

```
<textarea
  style="width: 100%; height: 70%; resize: none; border-color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; color: #000000;"
  id="text"/>
```

Comment: можно больше кода? res переменная интересует

Answer (score 2):

Исправьте сам тег `textarea` - должен быть закрывающий тег `</textarea>`:

```js
var res = "some text";

$("#text").val(res);
```

```html
<textarea
  style="width: 100%; height: 70%; resize: none; border-color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; color: #000000;"
  id="text"></textarea>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Исправил. Проблема осталась :(

Comment: Что у Вас в `res`, возможно там что-то не так?

Comment: В `res` определенно что-то не так